# SSL iOS9 SSLHandshake failed. I checked with openssl & my server works with tls 1.2V

Tags: ios, ssl, ios9, handshake

Im getting these errors from my app in iOS9.
It works great on iOS8.
My server is using tls v1.2. So, I dont know where is the problem.

```
2015-08-04 16:52:24.319 Entumano[676:59469] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-08-04 16:52:24.324 Entumano[676:59469] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer. In all post i read they were talking about tls version. BUT apple it's also validating that your ssl have this ciphers:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

I manage to workaround setting in plist NSAppTransportSecurity NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = NO

Comment: You answer led me to a question that discusses how to determine which cyphers a website supports: http://superuser.com/q/109213/51803

Comment: Also see this tech note from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/